# Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

Can anyone explain to me what this error means? I would appreciate it a lot for any kindof help with this.

```
<form class="form" id="form" action="/mailer.php" method="post">
```

The Jquery code I'm using for it is this.

```
$('#form').submit();
```

Comment: Try using `$('#form')[0].submit();` OR simply `document.getElementById('form').submit();` .. BTW, your current code should actually work..

Comment: It seems that there is a conflict on your page, prototype/mootools/...?

Comment: I'll try the first option in just one moment.

Second reply...
jquery.min.js

Comment: are you closing your form `</form>`?

Comment: @techfoobar he's selecting by `ID`.. It would only get the first matched element anyways

Comment: And $('#form')[0].submit(); OR simply document.getElementById('form').submit(); are not working. 

I'm going to upload the code to a text file and update my original post so everyone can take a look.

Comment: Do you have an input with the name submit?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Check the form to see whether there is a `HTMLInputElement` with id or name is `submit`.

This will set a property `submit` to the `HTMLFormElement`, so the `submit` function which is in the prototype of the form element can't be executed.

***Example:***

```
<form class="form" id="form" action="/mailer.php" method="post">
    ​<input type="button" name="submit" value="go"/>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

js:

```
​console.log($("#form")[0].submit)​;​  // will be the button element, not the submit function.
```

jQuery's `.submit()` method will call the `.submit()` on the original dom element, so the error will happen.

Comment: There is a 'mock' submit input type="button" name="submit" so .. i'll remove the name and see if that works.

Comment: @AndrewAllenWest Yes, that must be the reason.

Comment: Bear in mind that jquery < 1.9 have a bug regarding the naming of submit button, ie: you cannot name submit button "submit" :) -  http://jsfiddle.net/JscKb/

Comment: That's not a bug. That's just how the underlying DOM works. There is a work around, but it doesn't work in versions of Internet Explorer that are officially supported by jQuery 1.9 and lower.

Comment: Just had a damn hard time find the solution for the same problem thank you very much!

Comment: Great catch that should save people from banging their heads against the table.

Answer (score 29):

**xdazz** explained the issue well.

You can use a native **submit** method of HTMLFormElement to work around a problem:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call($('#form')[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! This worked for me! Ironically this answer has no up votes.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!  This is great to execute forms in the console if they have this issue...  Which was the case on an IT comments form...

Comment: This is a good alternative if xdazz's solution is not enough!

Answer (score 7):

If you have a button or input with the name submit or id submit, I have seen errors in IE. Make sure your inputs are correctly named. Here's an article on it http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1414