# JQuery: Howto submit form that has submit-button with the name "submit"

Tags: jquery

I know that using `$('form').submit()` does not work when the submit button is named with the reserved name "submit".

The annoying thing is that I can't change the html of the form that I want to submit.

I thought a workaround would be to delete the input button before using `$('form').submit()`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$('input:last').remove();
$('form').submit();
```

Does anybody know another solution for this problem?

Comment: doesn't the form have an id or class or something like that?

Comment: or try `$('form[0]').submit();` and the number must correspond to the number of the form counting from start of the body

Comment: The form doesn't have an id or a class. But selecting the elements with my code does work. Manually removing the submit button in the html code is the solution for my problem, but when I try to do this using javascript the problem still exists.

Comment: alright, look at the comment i gave in the answer of NullPointer... mayby that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

*1.Create a formElement and use its `.submit` methods.*

```
document.createElement('form').submit.apply($('form')[0]);
```

*2.Use the `.submit` method form the prototype of `HTMLFormElement`*

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.apply($('form')[0]);
```

The reason is stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540953/property-submit-of-object-htmlformelement-is-not-a-function/12541054#12541054).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code i used once. It should work for you too.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
<input type="text" value="kdfhdjskfsdhf" name="test" />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit_this_form()" />
</form>

function submit_this_form(){
    jQuery($('input[name="submit"]')).attr('name', 'new_submit');
    jQuery('#myform').submit();
}
```