# form not submitting data to php

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms, get

I have created a form which onsubmit runs a function in another file (`results.php`)(files have been loaded using jQuery). However, I am uable to access the form inputs on the other file (`results.php`).

I created a test to see whether the array was even set, and it wasnt. Is there any way i can set the array on the form? If not, how do I access the inputs of the form in another php file?

Please beware that I cannot use `action="example.php"` as this loads a new page and I am trying to avoid this (using AJAX and jQuery).

Here is the form:

```
<form onsubmit="loadCatering();return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="venueName">Venue Name:</label></td>
            <td>
                <select id="venueName" name="venueName"required>
                    <option value = "1">Central Plaza</option>
                    <option value = "2">Pacific Towers</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="submit">Check Catering Grades:</label></td>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</html>
```

This is the script in `results.php` which attempts to access the data within the form:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['venueName'])){
    echo "yes";
}
else{
    echo "not set";
}
?>
```

Note - not set gets echoed when running this.

Also note, the function `loadCatering()` simply loads `results.php` using jQuery.If you would lke to see the contents of this function please let me know

Comment: I have made some edits

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586736/submitting-a-form-with-an-onsubmit

Comment: I use AJAX in a different way to this - I load using jQuery. therefore I am reluctant to change my whole code. is there an easier way?

Comment: If you want to submit form without refresh the page you need to use Ajax jQuery and make a post request with correct content-type

Comment: How do i do that? Currently i am using ajax jquiery but just using $(#element id).load("file name")

Comment: Is it still possible to do it like tjat?

Comment: Please help. I have been stuck on this issue for ages @Flyzzx

Comment: There are two ways for you to submit this form and have the variables in `$_GET`: the AJAX way that Dan Leach linked to and submitting the form regularly using `method=get`. That's it.

Comment: Just do `$("#element-id").load("results.php?venueName="+venueName)`?

Comment: Ashley is there any chance you could read through my problem. Given the way I have structured my code how do I get the variables in the form to another file

Comment: I have been stuck on this problem for days. Is there any chance I could open a private message with one of you guys and you can help me look through my code in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

try  these
**1) Insert name and method in form tag**
"`<form name="submit" action="result.php" method="GET" onsubmit="loadCatering();return false;" >`
**2) Insert same name in button tag too** 
"`<input type="submit" name="submit">submit</button><br>`
Then access using this
`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: Where do i put that login? In results.php?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with button tag too login? I dont have a button tag to login. I only have a submit button.

Comment: What is the class register button?

Comment: Also where do i try access it?? In the same file ? or in results.php

Comment: Its my own code from my own project just shown you as you can get the concep

Comment: Would you be able to apply that to my concept? It would mean a lot

Comment: action = "result.php"

Comment: Didnt work. For starters, it loads up a new page, secondly, it still says not set