# form reset button conflict with jquery reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, form-submit

I encounter something weird. I have the following form:

```
<form id="addExpenseForm" name="addExpenseForm" data-bind="submit: addExpense">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="save" id="submit" name="submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset" id="reset" name="reset" />
</form>
```

As you can see, there is a `reset` button inside to clear all the `form`.

---

I am using `Knockout.js` to bind the `submit` of the `form` and `reset` it this way...

```
self.addExpense = function (formElement) {
  $('#addExpenseForm')[0].reset();
};
```

Everything seems good but I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'reset' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function
```

And I can't figure out why I get this because my code is correct and the strange part is that the code works fine when removing the `reset` button.

How can I solve this? Is there a kind of conflict when using `reset()` method and `reset` button at the same time?

Just to know, I made this `jsfiddle` to test removing the `reset` button and verify what I am asking here.

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/vWNf7/

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of your code, and maybe the html used by the reset button?

Comment: FYI just updated answer with plenty of help! Hope you find what you need!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a big difference here. When using jQuery, DOM elements called via jQuery styling (exp. $("addExpenseForm")) are given "properties". How these properties are written and added depends on the Element and it's use (and other stuff here and there, but that's another lesson).

Suffice it to say, when you create the from WITHOUT the reset button, then the "property" reset is indeed a **function**! It will return the following value when queried: `function reset() { [native code] }`.

However, when you add the button manually (aka. you place it in the HTML), then reset becomes THAT BUTTON and NOT A function. In other words it will return something like `<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset" id="reset" name="reset" />`.

Herein is your problem ...

If the BUTTON is ADDED VIA HTML Then use:

```
$('#addExpenseForm')[0].reset.click();
```

Else, The Button is not `type="reset"`, but merely a button that says "reset" or just no button at all! Use:

```
$('#addExpenseForm')[0].reset();
```

## OR

wrap it all up in one big if statement!

```
if (typeof $('#addExpenseForm')[0].reset == "function") {
    $('#addExpenseForm')[0].reset();
}
else {
    $('#addExpenseForm')[0].reset.click();
}
```

And just for Grins and giggles, here is that IF statement in one line:

```
typeof $("#addExpenseForm")[0].reset == "function" ? $("#addExpenseForm")[0].reset() : $("#addExpenseForm")[0].reset.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the reset button id attribute from 'reset' to anything else.

See here for an explanation of why you are receiving the error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12541054/492325

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myform")[0].reset.click();
}
```