# event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false; not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, return-value, preventdefault

The Form still submits in IE even though there is `preventdefault` and `returnvalue = false`.
Everything is fine in Chrome and firefox.

I have also tried `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    var xxx = $('#xxx').val();
    var yyy = $('#yyy').val();
    var zzz = $('#zzz').val();
    var uuu = $('#uuu').val();
    if (zzz != '000000' && zzz != '') {
        validate_xxxyyy(uuu, function(response) {
            if (response === false) {
                if (xxx == '') {
                    alert("XXX undefined!");
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
                }
                else if (yyy == '') {
                    alert("yyy Undefined!");
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});

function validate_xxxyyy(uuu, callback) {
    var data_string = 'uuu=' + uuu;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: data_string,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is around [deffered functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

your success function in:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: data_string,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            callback(response);
        }
    });
```

Is defferred. Think of it as threaded. So the `submit` continues without waiting for the callback to happen. So it doesn't call `event.preventDefault()`, or more precisly, it does but it's too late, the submit has already returned.

I would change what ever is calling this from a submit button (which I'm guessing it is currently) to a normal button then validate it, then only submit the form if this validation succeeds using `$('form').submit();`.

```
$('#button').click(function(event) {
    var xxx = $('#xxx').val();
    var yyy = $('#yyy').val();
    var zzz = $('#zzz').val();
    var uuu = $('#uuu').val();
    if (zzz != '000000' && zzz != '') {
        validate_xxxyyy(uuu, function(response) {
            if (response === false) {
                if (xxx == '') {
                    alert("XXX undefined!");

                }
                else if (yyy == '') {
                    alert("yyy Undefined!");

                }
            }
            else {
                $('#form1').submit();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#form1').submit();
    }
});

function validate_xxxyyy(uuu, callback) {
    var data_string = 'uuu=' + uuu;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: data_string,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You did notice the `async: false` ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The success function is deffered anyway. So the submit will always happen.

Comment: See my update. You'll need to refactor your code quite a bit. Problem is you can't just resubmit the form as it will hit the same code again.

Comment: @mend, added some code. you'll need to change the #button obviously and maybe your markup to not use a submit

Comment: I rewrote the code with <button> and jquery.click. My problem is that i have 2 forms in the page. #form and #form1 and i want to submit #form1. When i write $('form').submit(); it submits #form and $('#form1').submit(); doesn't do anything. Can you help me?

Comment: $('#form1').submit() doesn't do anything? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: there must be something else going on in there but I can't tell from what you've already posted.

Comment: I found the error.<button> name cannot be 'submit'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540953/property-submit-of-object-htmlformelement-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 2):

Start by preventing the form from submitting, do the ajax call for validation asynchronously, and if it validates you submit with the native submit which is not captured by the event handler :

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = this,
        xxx  = $('#xxx').val(),
        yyy  = $('#yyy').val(),
        zzz  = $('#zzz').val(),
        uuu  = $('#uuu').val();

    if (zzz != '000000' && zzz != '') {
        validate_xxxyyy(uuu).done(function(response) {
            if (!response) {
                if (xxx == '') {
                    alert("XXX undefined!");
                }
                else if (yyy == '') {
                    alert("yyy Undefined!");
                }
            }
            else {
                self.submit();
            }
        });
    } else {
        self.submit();
    }
});

function validate_xxxyyy(uuu) {
    var data_string = 'uuu=' + uuu;
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: data_string,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and most of it works but there is still a little error. self.submit(); that is inside validate_xxxyyy{} does not POST submit1 variable. That is the <input name='submit1'> What could be the problem?

Comment: `self.submit()` calls the native `submit` event, and submits the form exactly as it would if it where submitted with a button, so if you're missing something it's probably not filled out, doesn't have a name, or something else is wrong in the HTML, as `self.submit()` only submits the HTML elements just like they would have been submitted by the default `submit`.

Comment: Yeah, but the submit button itself doesn't get submitted. I can't understand what could be wrong with it. The last `self.submit();` that happens outside `validate_xxxyyy{}` posts submit button value nicely. `<input id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit1" value="Sisesta">`

Comment: That does seem very strange, as they are equal, and the ajax call doesn't change anything? Try changing `self.submit();` to `document.getElementById('form1').submit();` just to see if that changes anything ?

Comment: No luck. Everything else gets posted inside the form but not the submit button itself. I can write a hidden input for the time being but it would be interesting to solve it also.

Comment: Are you using jquery validate? Seems there's a bug https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/309

Answer (score -1):

Put : event.preventDefault() first like:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var xxx = $('#xxx').val();
    var yyy = $('#yyy').val();
    ...
```

Or you will need to override form onsubmit event to prevent submitting:

Comment: Completely missing the point. If he did this the form would **never** submit

Comment: How can you sumit a form via Ajax w/o stoping/pre ending its default behavior?

Comment: He's not. He's sending an async call to the server and **if** this succeeds he then submit's the form

Comment: How is my answer different from the one you selected as the right answer? He told you the same I did. (Palm in th face) - good luck

Comment: No he didn't. You simply said, preventDefault(). This does not solve the problem. The OP needs to prevent the default **then** submit the form manually only when the validation passes. If he did what you suggested, nothing would work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
    var xxx = $('#xxx').val();
    var yyy = $('#yyy').val();
    var zzz = $('#zzz').val();
    var uuu = $('#uuu').val();
    if (zzz != '000000' && zzz != '') {
        validate_xxxyyy(uuu, function(response) {
            if (!response) {
                if (xxx == '') {
                    alert("XXX undefined!");
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
                }
                else if (yyy == '') {
                    alert("yyy Undefined!");
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});
```