# form submission using tag <a> in jsp not working

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

I am trying to submit form from one jsp to an another jsp by using html tag  as below :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>SendIt Bank</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="css/bank.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

function checkUserInListAndSubmit() { 
    alert("hello");
    document.getElementById('userLoginForm').submit();
    //document.forms["userLogin"].submit();

}

</script>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<form name="userLoginForm" id="userLoginForm" action="accountdetails.jsp" method="POST">
    <table width="202" height="154" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> 
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" class="headermain">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" class="headermain"><div align="center" class="style4">Online
            Banking Login</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="loginbox style5">User ID:</td>
        <td class="loginbox"><input name="userID" type="text" id="userID" size="12" maxlength="20"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="68" class="loginbox style5">Password: </td>
        <td class="loginbox"><input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="12" maxlength="20"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="103"><div align="left"><a href="JavaScript:checkUserInListAndSubmit()"><img src="images/btn-signin.png" alt="Sign In" name="submit" width="60" height="20" border="0" align="right"></a></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><p align="center"><span class="style2"><a href="FYP1.html">Forgot
                your Password?</a><br>
        </span> </p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on href link, in my case i am clicking on a image. The contol goes to javascript function (). But, the form isn't getting submitted. When i try to debug in chrome i see this error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function index.jsp:12
checkUserInListAndSubmit index.jsp:12
(anonymous function)
```

The error is at line document.getElementById('userLoginForm').submit();
Kindly help me resolving this and submit the form.

Comment: ny reason u arent using input type="submit"?

Comment: Actually there is no reason of not using input. I have been given a standard template in which i have <a> tags only. So, i am trying to achieve from the same as that should be achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason u aren't using input type="submit"?

Anyways this is your answer

```
<form id="userLoginForm'" action="" method="post">
    <a href="JavaScript:checkUserInListAndSubmit()"><img src="images/btn-signin.png" alt="Sign In" name="submit" width="60" height="20" border="0" align="right" onclick="document.getElementById('userLoginForm'').submit();"></a>
</form>
```

Also

```
onclick="parentNode.submit();
```

should work

Comment: I tried it this way                                              <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="103"><div align="left"><a href="JavaScript:checkUserInListAndSubmit()"><img src="images/btn-signin.png" alt="Sign In" name="submit" width="60" height="20" border="0" align="right" onclick="parentNode.submit();"></a></div></td>
   </tr>                                                         I get two errors in chrome console. With the old error i get this error                                                        Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.jsp:49
onclick

Answer (score 0):

Try with this anchor tag,

```
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('userLoginForm').submit();">
```

Or if you want to do more as js function,

```
    <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="checkUserInListAndSubmit();return false;">
```

**Updated Answer**

1. specify your anchor with id, e.g;

   ```
   <a href="#" id="mylink">
   ```
2. write js function for anchor tag onclick listener

   ```
   document.getElementById("mylink").onclick = function() {
       //do other coding here
       document.getElementById("userLoginForm").submit();
       return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: I have some functionality to be achieved in js function before submitting form. So, i cannot submit directly on click.

Comment: I tried the updated solution. I am back to my first error :( Still its not submitting the form to the target jsp

Comment: I tried update solution. url changed by appending with #. But, form submitting dint happen. I see this error in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null index.jsp:10
(anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

From your markup, remove/rename the attribute

```
name="submit"
```

That is,

```
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="103"><div align="left"><a href="JavaScript:checkUserInListAndSubmit()"><img src="images/btn-signin.png" alt="Sign In" width="60" name="some-other-name" height="20" border="0" align="right"></a></div></td>
  </tr>
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12541054) for more information.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried this <td width="103"><div align="left"><a href="JavaScript:checkUserInListAndSubmit()"><img src="images/btn-signin.png" alt="Sign In" name="somename" width="60" height="20" border="0" align="right"></a></div></td> But, i still get this error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function index.jsp:29
checkUserInListAndSubmit index.jsp:29
(anonymous function)

Comment: did you try to inspect the page and make sure that the name was changed? try hard-refreshing the page. in my case, renaming the attribute worked.